# Weird situation with Scala Play - type inference

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

```
@(css: Option[String])(content: Html)(customJS: Option[Array[String]])

 @for(js <- customJS if !customJS.isEmpty) {
            <script src="@routes.Assets.at(js)"></script>
        }
```

I was writing for this small for-comprehension that will loop through and print out the uri String. Since it is possible to be none, or an array of Strings, I used `Option`.

Then the complier from typesafe activator told me that `@routes.Assets.at()` is supposed to take a `String` not an `Array[String]`. I'm in shock because js is supposed to be `String` right?

Then I tried to write like this:

```
 @for(js <- customJS if !customJS.isEmpty) {
      @var uri = js
            <script src="@routes.Assets.at(js)"></script>
        }
```

Then the complier said that added line is illegal start of "simple expression".

It is not a simple expression! It is a full for-comprehension with `{}`! Also I was eventually forced to use `js.asInstanceOf[String]` to fool the complier. I'm not glad with this because once I was told that I should never use `asInstanceOf`. So what's wrong with my original code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you should not use `Array` - use `Seq`.

There is no need in `Option[Seq[String]]` - use `Seq[String]`. Instead of `None` you could always use an empty `Seq`.

In case you still want to use `Option[Seq[String]]` you should rewrite your `for` like this:

```
@for(jsArray <- customJS; js <- jsArray) {
  <script src="@routes.Assets.at(js)"></script>
}
```

You don't need `if !customJS.isEmpty`. `Option` is something like collection with 1 or 0 elements. Element of `Option[Array[String]]` is `Array[String]`.

Comment: I see!! That's why!! But what about that illegal start of "simple expression"?

Comment: @WindDweller: I guess `@var` is just illegal statement. I can't find it in [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTemplates). You could use `@defining`. You could also add an additional variable in `for` like this: `@for(jsArray <- customJS; js <- jsArray; otherName = js)`.

Comment: Emmm.. sorry I tried to use `Seq` but it tells me: error: value foreach is not a member of object Seq

Comment: @WindDweller: You should replace `Array` with `Seq`. Replace `customJS: Option[Array[String]]` with `customJS: Seq[String]`.

Comment: @WindDweller: `error: value foreach is not a member of object Seq` means you've tried to compile something like `for(_ <- Seq)`.

Comment: Sorry..yes that's my fault. I throw `Seq` directly into the parentheses. I now changed it to `Seq()`. However, how I don't want any of the `script` tag being printed if `Seq` contains nothing right? So I probably still need to use guard...

Comment: @WindDweller: If `Seq` is empty you'll get no `script` tags. `for` body executed once per element of `Seq`. No elements - no `script`s.

Comment: @WindDweller: guard is just a filter to `Seq`. Filter for empty collection is pointless.